# How to generate temporary downloads in Flask?

Tags: python, apache, flask

I have a Flask app that lets users download MP3 files. How can I make it so the URL for the download is only valid for a certain time period?

For example, instead of letting anyone simply go to `example.com/static/sound.mp3` and access the file, I want to validate each request to prevent an unnecessary amount of bandwidth.

I am using an Apache server although I may consider switching to another if it's easier to implement this. Also, I don't want to use Flask to serve the file because this would cause a performance overhead by forcing Flask to directly serve the file to the user. Rather, it should use Apache to serve the file.

Comment: check the datetime and return different things?

Answer (score 0):

You could use S3 to host the file with a temporary URL. Use Flask to upload the file to S3 (using boto3), but use a dynamically-generated temporary key.

Example URL: `http://yourbucket.s3.amazon.com/static/c258d53d-bfa4-453a-8af1-f069d278732c/sound.mp3`

Then, when you tell the user where to download the file, give them that URL. You can then delete the S3 file at the end of the time period using a cron job.

This way, Amazon S3 is serving the file directly, resulting in a complete bypass of your Flask server.

Comment: You can also leave the files on S3 and use expiring URLs.